Ubuntu 24.04 can not install libgnome-keyring
I have a fresh installation of ubuntu 24.04 and want to use the nextcloud desktop client. After connecting the client with my nextcloud the login credentials should be stored in gnome-keyring, but they are not.
Other people with the same issue suggest to install the library libgnome-keyring. But I can't there is no such library in ubuntu 24.04. Where can i find it, or what is the alternative?
